# FFT Example for J2me

Tags: java, audio, java-me, fft

Anybody can please provide me example or tutorial of FFT(Fast Fourier Transformation) for fetching audio frequency.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[splMeter](http://code.google.com/p/splmeter/) has used FFT for fetchine audio frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my functions:

http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/The_Fast_Fourier_Transform_in_Java_%28part_1%29

They are quite portable, and even if I've not tested them with j2me they SHOULD do the trick anyway.

Comment: your functions use `Math sin/cos` are you aware that these are not available in J2ME CLDC?

Comment: I see. Also, iirc ([your page](http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/The_Fast_Fourier_Transform_in_Java_%28part_1%29) seems suspended now) your functions use double - are you aware that CLDC 1.0 does not support double?

Comment: (yes, we're having some problem with host).I'm really sorry, but as I said before "I've not tested them with j2me".