# Converting ArrayList<Double> to Double Array and vice-versa for JAVA/Android

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to convert a Double ArrayList to a Double Array and vice-versa.

This is the code I have for converting Double ArrayList to Double Array, but the program keeps on crashing.
Am I missing something? or is the logic wrong all together?

```
ArrayList<Double> numsy = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> numsx = new ArrayList<Double>();  
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    numsy.add((double)generator.nextFloat());
    numsx.add((double)j);
}
double[] arrayX = new double[numsx.size()];     
double[] arrayY = new double[numsy.size()];
//assigns array x and y the values in the list.
for (int k1 = 0; k1 < numsy.size(); i++) {
    double f = numsy.get(k1);
    arrayY[k1] = f;
    f = numsx.get(k1);
    arrayX[k1] = f;
}
FFT doFFT = new FFT(4);
doFFT.fft(arrayX, arrayY);
//adding the FFT numbers back to the Lists
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    numsy.add(arrayY[j]);
    numsx.add(arrayX[j]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your `generator`?

Comment: @Yogendra this is possibly a `Random` object.

Comment: What type of exception or error?

Comment: @YogendraSingh the FFT class? its taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272232/fft-library-in-android-sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are instantiating your `Arrays` **before adding** values in your `ArrayLists`:

```
double[] arrayX = new double[numsx.size()];     
double[] arrayY = new double[numsy.size()];
```

This will create arrays with `length`: **0**. Then you'll have a null pointer in your loop below.

**UPDATE**

Then you have to edit your loop:

```
for (int k1 = 0; k1 < numsy.size(); i++) {
```

to this

```
for (int k1 = 0; k1 < numsy.size(); k1++) {
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Try again.

Comment: I am such a fool! Thank you so much. I have even added the remaining piece of code that adds the manipulated numbers back to the list. does that logic seem right? It works just fine, but is it there a way to make it even better?

Comment: I don't see any problems with it. :)

Comment: okay thanks :) I was just wondering if I could make it more dynamic and dont relay on that 100 value again and again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Double> numsy = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> numsx = new ArrayList<Double>();

 for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
     numsy.add((double)generator.nextFloat());
     numsx.add((double)j);
 }
```

**//Declare arrayX and arrayY after adding values to numX and numY**

```
 double[] arrayX = new double[numsx.size()];     
 double[] arrayY = new double[numsy.size()];     
    //assigns array x and y the values in the list.
 for (int k1 = 0; k1 < numsy.size(); k1++) {
   double f = numsy.get(k1);
   arrayY[k1] = f;
   f = numsx.get(k1);
   arrayX[k1] = f;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Ram, even then the program is not working, its still crashing the program. saying that the application is not responding.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try to use the built-in method:
`double[] arrayX = numsx.toArray(new double[0]);`
`double[] arrayY = numsY.toArray(new double[0]);`

Comment: I did not know a method like this existed in java. I've worked with python for most of my life so far. so my experience with java is very little. let me read more about it

Comment: it gives me the following error,
the method toArray(T[]) in the type ArrayList<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (double[])

Comment: Oh, my mistake, use `toArray(new Double[0]);`

Comment: it says cannot convert from Double[] to double[]

Comment: @Jonathan well, so you'll have to use an array of Doubles, but this won't make problems when retrieving the actual values. You can say: `double value = aDoubleArray[2];` and as well, `double d = 2.4;  aDoubleArray[2] = d;` the autoboxing and unboxing of java are really wonderful.