# Fast Fourier Transform in Android

Tags: eclipse, signals, fft

Where can I find a free, very quick, and reliable implementation of FFT in Android? Only I have left to do a porting of the FFT of Matlab in Android to finish the Proyect of the end of career. Thank you for all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFT library in android Sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272232/fft-library-in-android-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out: [FFT library in android Sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272232/fft-library-in-android-sdk)

I personally am using JFFT pack which runs smoothly at analysing audio with an fft window size of 2048.

Comment: I had tryed to do with these code, but when I put to Run, it didn't do anything because the log-cat didn't kept run... why this? I need to do one interfaz and later do these porting, my teacher tell me that this work is easy but I'm lost now. @ user2262830

Comment: What I can do to run this?