# Android Catch Properties of Playing Sounds

Tags: android

Is there any way to get bass or treble values of playing music from microphone in 
 Android ? I mean that i want to analyze music with the help of these values(not spesifically bass or treble , any band can be useful)

Comment: what you want is called a spectrum analysis. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293953/how-to-develop-a-spectrum-analyser-from-a-realtime-audio

Comment: Yes , thank you Vlad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop a Spectrum Analyser from a realtime audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293953/how-to-develop-a-spectrum-analyser-from-a-realtime-audio)