# How do you interpret the frequencies produced by the output of a FFT

Tags: math, audio, signal-processing, fft

When you perform an FFT, the frequencies of each of the elements in the output array are represented by:

Frequency at element k is f(k) = k/NT

Where N is the number of samples (hence number of elements in the output array) and T is the time slide in seconds.  f is measured in HZ

My question is, given that formula, the frequency of each element will always be less than 1 HZ and the FFT can never produce higher than 1HZ frequencies

So how do you operate on the higher frequencies?  Like the ones the human ear can hear (20HZ to 20KHZ)

Thanks
D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Frequency from FFT result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about the sampling frequency. So imagine you're havin a sample rate of 48 kHz, which is pretty common. Now you are performing a FFT with `N = 1024` points over your data. Then you are able to assign each `n in N` a specific frequency. How is this done? Just assume that `N` equals the sampling rate. Now you are able to retrieve an equation for every other `n`. The bigger you choose `N` the finer the spacings of the frequencies get.

**Edit** Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result) related / similar SO question, especially the answer from Paul R is very helpful.

Comment: Help me with an example.  I have 44100 samples per second in time domain.  Now I feed to my FFT, 512 samples for a 11ms period.  Because I get 512 samples every 11ms (this provides me the 44100 samples per second).  Now in my output vector of the FFT, I have 512 frequency domain samples.  What frequency will the element at position 100 in the output array represent?

Comment: Made an edit with a link to another SO question, this answers your question completely.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually thats a great answer.  One last question... what if my sample rate is 44100 samples per second, but I only feed the FFT 11ms worth of data?  That is, the 512 samples do not cover the entire 44100 sample range.  Will the output array still cover the entire frequency range till 44100 HZ?

Comment: Well it all depends on the resulting sampling frequency, i.e. if you are sampling with 22 kHz you'll only get signals up to 11 kHz, got it? It's always f/2. So if you are sampling for 11 ms but getting new data every 1 ns you can calculate the frequency, so it's not about "how long" but "how often".

Comment: Most confused answer possible!

Comment: Feel free to improve @FrankPuck