# DFT function implementation in C

Tags: c, fft

I am working on implementation of BFSK implementation on a DSP processor and am currently simulating it on a LINUX machine using C. I am working on the demodulation function and it involves taking a FFT of the incoming data. For simulation purposes, I have a pre-defined function for DFT which is:

```
void dft(complex_float* in, complex_float* out, int N, int inv)
{
    int i, j;
    float a, f;
    complex_float s, w;
    f = inv ? 1.0/N : 1.0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        s.re = 0;
        s.im = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a = -2*PI*i*j/N;
        if (inv) a = -a;
        w.re = cos(a);
        w.im = sin(a);
        s.re += in[j].re * w.re - in[j].im * w.im;
        s.im += in[j].im * w.re + in[j].re * w.im;
    }
    out[i].re = s.re*f;
    out[i].im = s.im*f;
}
```

Here the `complex_float` is a struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
 float re;
 float im;
} complex_float;
```

In the `dft()` function, the parameter `N` denotes the number of DFT points.

My doubt is that since the algorithm also involves a frequency hopping sequence, while demodulating the signal, I need to check the amplitude of DFT of the signal at different frequency components.

In MATLAB this was quite simple as the FFT function there involves the sampling frequency as well and I could find the power at any frequency point as

```
powerat_at_freq = floor((freq * fftLength) / Sampling_freq)
```

But the C function does not involve any frequencies, so how can I determine the magnitude of the DFT at any particular frequency?

Comment: Try posting on [DSP stackexchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just a nit: your code is not FFT, it is the O(N^2) direct implementation of a DFT.  You might want to check out kissfft.sourceforge.net for a C FFT.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding : I am using the DFT function just for code testing , the simulation and implementation is some using a separate compiler which uses different function for computing the FFT of a complex signal...

Answer (score 3):

The index in the FFT table for a particular frequency is calculated as follows:

```
int i = round(f / fT*N)
```

where `f` is the wanted frequency, `fT` is the sampling frequency and `N` is the number of FFT points.
The FFT should be fine-grained enough (i.e. N should be large) to cover all the frequencies.
If the precise frequency isn't present in the FFT, the nearest one will be used. More
info about FFT indexes versus frequencies:

[How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

Comment: I was also thinking on similar lines (its calculated in MATLAB in the same way). However, I am a bit confused as the `fft()` that I am using  doesnt consider the sampling frequency being used.

Comment: Discrete Fourier transforms by itself are completely frequency-agnostic, they use [normalized frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_frequency) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency represented depends on the sample rate of the data fed to it (divided by the length if the FFT).  Thus any DFT or FFT can represent any frequency you want just by feeding it the right amount of data at the right sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the FFTW library which is famous and useful in the applicational area of FFT.

The official website is: http://www.fftw.org/

By the way, the matlab's FFT function is also implemented through the FFTW library.

Comment: FFTW is licensed under the GPL with an option to buy from MIT--good to remember depending on what you're doing.