# How to detect the value for lowest and highest frequency in aurioTouch project

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, frequency, frequency-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Frequency from FFT result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

I'm investigating [aurioTouch2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.
And in draw view function one function is always called to compute fft data, so we can compute power for different frequencies.

```
Boolean FFTBufferManager::ComputeFFT(int32_t *outFFTData)
{
    if (HasNewAudioData())
    {


        //Generate a split complex vector from the real data
        // real1 = -0.005138, real2 = -0.005010;     r = -0.005138, im = -0.005010   
        vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)mAudioBuffer, 2, &mDspSplitComplex, 1, mFFTLength);

        //Take the fft and scale appropriately
        // FFTSetup mSpectrumAnalysis - koefficients
        vDSP_fft_zrip(mSpectrumAnalysis, &mDspSplitComplex, 1, mLog2N, kFFTDirection_Forward);
        vDSP_vsmul(mDspSplitComplex.realp, 1, &mFFTNormFactor, mDspSplitComplex.realp, 1, mFFTLength);
        vDSP_vsmul(mDspSplitComplex.imagp, 1, &mFFTNormFactor, mDspSplitComplex.imagp, 1, mFFTLength);

        //Zero out the nyquist value
        mDspSplitComplex.imagp[0] = 0.0;

        //Convert the fft data to dB
        // calculate complex number abs, write to tmpData
        Float32 tmpData[mFFTLength];
        vDSP_zvmags(&mDspSplitComplex, 1, tmpData, 1, mFFTLength);

        //In order to avoid taking log10 of zero, an adjusting factor is added in to make the minimum value equal -128dB
        vDSP_vsadd(tmpData, 1, &mAdjust0DB, tmpData, 1, mFFTLength);
        Float32 one = 1;
        vDSP_vdbcon(tmpData, 1, &one, tmpData, 1, mFFTLength, 0);

        //Convert floating point data to integer (Q7.24)
        vDSP_vsmul(tmpData, 1, &m24BitFracScale, tmpData, 1, mFFTLength);
        for(UInt32 i=0; i<mFFTLength; ++i)
            outFFTData[i] = (SInt32) tmpData[i];

        OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier(&mHasAudioData);
        OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(&mNeedsAudioData);
        mAudioBufferCurrentIndex = 0;
        return true;
    }
    else if (mNeedsAudioData == 0)
        OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(&mNeedsAudioData);

    return false;
}
```

The question is how to get the variety of frequencies I display in the screen?
I mean, I have the array of power for different audio frequencies. And how can I understand, what the value for lowest frequency, for example?

**Update to show my point of view:**

I know, that lowest threshold value (the lowest frequency) is outFFTData[0] and highest is outFFTData[last]. But I don't know, what frequency in figures relates to outFFTData[0], for example. Is outFFTData[0] relates to 16Hz; and is outFFTData[last] relates to 22 kHz?

Now I think, that outFFTData[0] relates to lowest frequency of audio, that a man can hear; and outFFTData[last] relates to highest frequency of audio, that a man can hear.

Am I wrong?

**Update 2**

I looked at [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627). It really shows almost everything.
But, please, correct me, if I'm wrong:

In this code:

```
//Generate a split complex vector from the real data
        // real1 = -0.005138, real2 = -0.005010;     r = -0.005138, im = -0.005010   
        vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)mAudioBuffer, 2, &mDspSplitComplex, 1, mFFTLength);
//Take the fft and scale appropriately
        // FFTSetup mSpectrumAnalysis - koefficients
        vDSP_fft_zrip(mSpectrumAnalysis, &mDspSplitComplex, 1, mLog2N, kFFTDirection_Forward);
        vDSP_vsmul(mDspSplitComplex.realp, 1, &mFFTNormFactor, mDspSplitComplex.realp, 1, mFFTLength);
        vDSP_vsmul(mDspSplitComplex.imagp, 1, &mFFTNormFactor, mDspSplitComplex.imagp, 1, mFFTLength);
```

In this code    `mFFTLength = mAudioBufferLen / 2;`, so I think , that max value of frequency will be in mDspSplitComplex at `index = mFFTLength - 1`
Or may be I'm wrong and max value of frequency will be in mDspSplitComplex at `index = mFFTLength / 2 - 1`?

**Update 3**

I have very simular issue [Why do we use only the first buffer in aurioTouch project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503139/why-do-we-use-only-the-first-buffer-in-auriotouch-project).
May be anyone knows the answer.

Comment: About my update 2: mFFTLength - is the lenght of complex data, but we need only half of it, so the max value of frequency relates to )(mFFTLength / 2 - 1) element. And that's why mBufferLen in Apple code = 1024 = mFFTLength / 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be energy at some level in *all* of the FFT output bins - you need to decide upon a threshold value and then find the bins whose magnitude exceeds this threshold.

As for interpreting the corresponding frequency for each output bin, see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056).

Comment: I updated my the question, please, look at it.

Comment: The edit hasn't shown up yet - it looks like you are using multiple StackOverflow logins and you edited under a different pseudonym than you originally posted under. You should probably just stick to one login to avoid confusion.

Comment: We are a team of developers, that's why  the question was updated by the other guy from our team. But I fixed the issue with update, so now you should see it

Comment: Anyway, if you don't see, here it is:
I know, that lowest threshold value (the lowest frequency) is outFFTData[0] and highest is outFFTData[last]. But I don't know, what frequency in figures relates to outFFTData[0], for example. Is outFFTData[0] relates to 16Hz; and is outFFTData[last] relates to 22 kHz?

Now I think, that outFFTData[0] relates to lowest frequency of audio, that a man can hear; and outFFTData[last] relates to highest frequency of audio, that a man can hear.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I've looked at your link. It's the answer!

Comment: One more question, I updated my topic to "Update 2", please, comment this. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a real-to-complex FFT with mFFTLength real inputs and mFFTLength/2 complex outputs (the other mFFTLength/2 complex outputs are symmetrical and are ignored). Note that a complex output point is twice the size of a real input point. The calculation of output bin frequency remains the same though, i.e. complex output bin n corresponds to frequency Fs * n / mFFTLength.

Comment: I have the other little issue "Why do we use only the first buffer in aurioTouch project". I insert link to the issue in "Update 3". Please, look at it. Thank you so much!!!