# Why do we use only the first buffer in aurioTouch project

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, fft, frequency

I'm investigating [aurioTouch2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.
And I noticed, that when we analize audio data, we use only the first buffer of this data, and never other buffers.
in `void FFTBufferManager::GrabAudioData(AudioBufferList *inBL)` function:

```
    UInt32 bytesToCopy = min(inBL->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize, mAudioBufferSize - mAudioBufferCurrentIndex * sizeof(Float32));
    memcpy(mAudioBuffer+mAudioBufferCurrentIndex, inBL->mBuffers[0].mData, bytesToCopy);
```

in function

```
static OSStatus PerformThru(
                            void                        *inRefCon, 
                            AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, 
                            const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp, 
                            UInt32                      inBusNumber, 
                            UInt32                      inNumberFrames, 
                            AudioBufferList             *ioData)
if (THIS->displayMode == aurioTouchDisplayModeOscilloscopeWaveform)
{
        AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer(THIS->audioConverter, inNumberFrames, ioData, THIS->drawABL);
        SInt8 *data_ptr = (SInt8 *)(THIS->drawABL->mBuffers[0].mData);
}
```

The question is why do we ignore data in inBL->mBuffers[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html).mData?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's only 1 mic on your iPhone, the samples in the 2 stereo channel buffers (L and R) are identical.  Since the second buffer is just redundant (or in some configurations empty), that data there doesn't need to be analyzed (again).

Answer (score 0):

May be, I'm wrong, but there is now difference, what buffer to use. You have only 2 buffers:
mBuffers[0] and mBuffers[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH6SC.jpg). I tried to use buffer 0 in spectrogram and than buffer 1 (pronouncing equal sounds). Left  part of image was done, using buffer 0; right part - using buffer 1 (right peak was made during making of snapshot).

So, you can see , there is no difference.

[image]