# Signal processing (in Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, signals

I have a sensor that I am reading from, currently the code is in Java, but I dont think the issue is language specific, more approach related.

The sensor produces a signal with high and low pulses, roughly like a heartbeat. However, the "high" pulse is not always the same level, nor is the "low". What I am interested in is the relative difference. However, this alone is not enough, as within a single "session" the high and low values may also change (think a curved mid point)

Ive included an image of the 4 "types" of signals I would like to be able to handle. Top left is the "ideal" I'm fairly sure I can already handle that, the other three sadly are more common and less easy to handle.

My current approach has been to look for the average of the data, and see how many times that point is crossed, which will tell me how many high and low pulses there were.

I'd like to know if there is a simple way of detecting the high and low pulse, without using the averaging method.

[image]

Comment: I think you will need some type of averaging method, but you do not necessarily have to average over the whole signal.  You may be able to use a boxcar filter.

Comment: So do you want the average difference between a peak and the trough that comes immediately after (and vice versa) or you want to know the frequency of the wave?

Comment: Its the frequency of the wave I need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you stated you wanted to extract the frequency of the wave the first thing I thought of was a fourier transform; this converts the signal from the time domain to the frequency domain. Given the following sample wave:

[image]

This is a sine way to which I have added noise and a trend. The underlying sine wave has a frequency of 1.5Hz

You get this fourier transform

[image]

Here you can see a large response at 0hz, this is the linear trend and we can ignore it in this case. After that you can see one peak in the response at 1.5Hz, the frequency of our input signal. In other words; once you have the fourier transform your result is the data point with the largest value (after you remove the very low frequency results)

## Java Code

Apachi commons has a fast fourier transform class which I used to create this transformation. It takes as an input the sampled data for your wave and outputs a complex number, the modulus of the complex number (the square root of the real part squared plus the imaginary part squared) is [equal to the energy at that frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086626/2187042). Each entry `i` in the outputted array referes to the frequency at `i*samplingFrequency/noOfSamples`.

However the java code below largly deals with these issues for you. The only issue with the fast fourier transform is that the number of input entries must be a power of 2.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex;
import org.apache.commons.math3.transform.DftNormalization;
import org.apache.commons.math3.transform.FastFourierTransformer;
import org.apache.commons.math3.transform.TransformType;

public class FourierTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        double samplingFrequency=10; //hz, You will know this from your data and need to set it here
        
        

        double[] frequencyDomain = new double[input.length];

        FastFourierTransformer transformer = new FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.STANDARD);
        try {           
            Complex[] complex = transformer.transform(input, TransformType.FORWARD);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < complex.length; i++) {               
                double real = (complex[i].getReal());
                double imaginary = (complex[i].getImaginary());

                frequencyDomain[i] = Math.sqrt((real * real) + (imaginary * imaginary));
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        //only to frequencyDomain.length/2 since second half is mirror image or first half
        for(int i=0;i<frequencyDomain.length/2;i++){
            double frequency=samplingFrequency*i/frequencyDomain.length;
            System.out.println("Frequency: " + frequency + "\t\tEnergyComponent: " + frequencyDomain[i]);
        }
    }
    
    static double[]  input = new double[]{
            0.017077407 , //sample at 0 seconds
            1.611895528 , //sample at 0.1 seconds
            2.063967663 , //sample at 0.2 seconds
            1.598492541 , //etc
            0.184678933 ,
            0.02654732  ,
            0.165869218 ,
            1.026139745 ,
            1.914179294 ,
            2.523684208 ,
            1.71795312  ,
            0.932131202 ,
            1.097366772 ,
            1.107912105 ,
            2.843777623 ,
            2.503608192 ,
            2.540595787 ,
            2.048111122 ,
            1.515498608 ,
            1.828077941 ,
            2.400006658 ,
            3.562953532 ,
            3.34333491  ,
            2.620231348 ,
            2.769874641 ,
            2.423059324 ,
            2.11147835  ,
            3.473525478 ,
            4.504105599 ,
            4.325642774 ,
            3.963498242 ,
            2.842688545 ,
            2.573038184 ,
            3.434226007 ,
            4.924115479 ,
            4.876122332 ,
            4.553580015 ,
            3.92554604  ,
            3.804585546 ,
            3.476610932 ,
            4.535171252 ,
            5.398007229 ,
            5.729933758 ,
            5.573444511 ,
            4.487695977 ,
            4.133046459 ,
            4.796637209 ,
            5.091399617 ,
            6.420441446 ,
            6.473462022 ,
            5.663322311 ,
            4.866446009 ,
            4.840966187 ,
            5.329697081 ,
            6.746910181 ,
            6.580067494 ,
            7.140083322 ,
            6.243532245 ,
            4.960520462 ,
            5.100901901 ,
            6.794495306 ,
            6.959324497 ,
            7.194674358 ,
            7.035874424 

        };
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting, I havent got time right now to go into any depth with my response, but something that I see which may cause a problem: What happens if the frequency of the wave is less than 1? Will it be possible to differentiate between the real result and the "very low frequency result"?

Comment: @ZackNewsham The nice thing about fourier is that its all naturally in arbitary units. What matters is that the sampling frequency is higher than frequencys you care about, that you have at least a few periods of the wave in the time your sampling and the linear portion doesn't wipe out the wave (e.g. the wave goes from 0 to 1 in 20 seconds but the linear movement has gone to 1000 in that time isn't going to work). So if it looks like my first graph, whatever the units; seconds, milliseconds, millenia you'll get a graph that looks like the the second; but its units will be in KHz, Hz or nHz

Answer (score 2):

Find the point at which the direction of change changes. In calculus terms this is the second derivative.

Basically you are looking for the point where `sign(f(x)-f(x-1))` is opposite `sign(f(x+1)-f(x))`

Depending on your data acquisition there are a few ways to do this. If you add some more info about your specific problem I will edit the answer to help more.

Comment: Will this still work if the signal is not symmetric? I.e. The upward slope is steeper than the downward, or vice versa?

Comment: yes, all you are doing is finding the inflection points. Mind you this method assumes that you are getting data points along the curve, rather than a high point, low point, high point pattern.

Comment: Purely a direction change was not enough (due to noise on the signal) I ended up looking for a substantial direction change, and this turned out to be relatively accurate.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, you just need the high frequencies. Use a [high-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation)

Comment: it appears I need to know the frequency of the wave to use this.

Comment: Yes, but you could start with a low cutoff frequency and increase it until only the very-high frequencies are being passed.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, what is needed here is the height of the peak relative to the neighbouring troughs. I have created a library which can deal with such scenarios using what I call spike detection. The library is called [jDSP](https://jdsp.dev) and provides an utility called Spike Detection.

A demonstration of spike detection can be found [here](https://github.com/psambit9791/jdsp/wiki/Spike-Detection-and-Filtering) and what can be done is to identify peak heights relative to neighbouring troughs and then, filter using specific values.

[image]

The orange crosses represent the peaks detected.

Comment: Any reason behind the downvote would be appreciated.
I understood the problem as being one of detecting local peaks which is solved with this specific library's utility.