# Frequency of sound FFT

Tags: c#, .net, fft, naudio

I have one problem. I'm using NAudio, on C#. My Sample rate = 40960. My microphone, give me buffer every 100ms(4096 bytes). I send this to fft. If I look to only 4096 elements, correct to say about sound frequency more than 2048 Hz? Or I need to use for this buffer size more than this?

Comment: You seem to keep asking almost the same question over and over again - maybe you need to read a good introductory book on DSP if you're having trouble understanding the answers that people are giving you ?

Answer (score 4):

Your sample rate, Fs = 40960 Hz, therefore your FFT will represent real positive frequencies from 0 to Fs / 2 (Nyquist) = 0 Hz to 20480 Hz.

The *resolution* of your FFT is Fs / N = 40960 / 4096 = 10 Hz. So each bin is 10 Hz wide, and the first 2048 complex output bins represents frequencies from 0 to 20480 Hz in 10 Hz increments (you can ignore the other 2048 output bins since they contain no additional information for a purely real input signal).

For a more complete explanation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627).