# What is the range of the values returned by analyser.getByteFrequencyData in the web audio API?

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

I would like to work with percentages while doing some FFT with the web audio API.

To do so I need to know the range of the values the `analyser.getByteFrequencyData` returns.

I can't find anything about that, maybe someone knows?

Thanks

Comment: The range is 0-255.

For more information see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/14789992/4303873

Comment: thanks @Joriktos, if you post it as an answer, i'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

analyser.getByteFrequencyData returns a normalized array of values between 0 and 255.

The length of the array is half the value of analyzer.fftSize.
So if analyzer.fftSize = 1024 analyser.getByteFrequencyData will return an array with 512 values.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789992/4303873 for more information.