# Relationship between bins in frequency vector and the frequency peaks

Tags: fft, frequency, bins

I would like to know if there is any general relationship between bins of frequencies and peak frequency: say a wave x=Asin(2*pi*w*t +phi), goes through fft and fftshift to get both the positive and negative frequencies (-w and w Hz), say the frequency domain was given for example
f = f=linspace(-fs/2, fs/2, L); where fs is sampling frequency and L is the length of the fft or any other way. How do you find the bin where w and -w are? other than looking through the output data and finding int by hand?
How does fft give back the frequencies?
Thank you...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Frequency from FFT result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

Comment: How is that a dup if that was not even my question? maybe you should say"possible similarities not dups"...

Comment: If you look at the answers to the linked question they cover pretty much everything you asked above.