# Calculate Frequency from sound input using FFT

Tags: android, signal-processing, fft

My app. is displaying the peak frequency of input sound in RPM .. i have array of doubles contains the samples in time domain.

```
audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
```

Then i did FFT on it .

```
transformer.ft(toTransform);
```

using this class [Here](http://herschel.esac.esa.int/hcss-doc-10.0/load/hcss_drm/api/herschel/ia/numeric/toolbox/xform/util/ComplexDoubleFFT.html)

then i got the max magnitude of complex values which are the results of FFT

// block size  = 1024

```
double magnitude[] = new double[blockSize / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < magnitude.length; i++) {
                double R = toTransform[2 * i] * toTransform[2 * i];
                double I = toTransform[2 * i + 1] * toTransform[2 * i * 1];

                magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt(I + R);
            }
            int maxIndex = 0;
            double max = magnitude[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < magnitude.length; i++) {
                if (magnitude[i] > max) {
                    max = magnitude[i];
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
```

Now i got the index of the max magnitude ... 
1 - How can i get the Peak Frequency in details pls ?
2 - Is there any ready function called ComputeFrequency()  or getFrequency() ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency corresponding to a given FFT bin index is given by:

```
f = i * Fs / N;
```

where:

```
Fs = sample rate (Hz)
N = FFT size
i = bin index
```

So for your peak index `maxIndex` and FFT size `blockSize` the frequency of the peak will be:

```
f = maxIndex * Fs / blockSize;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627) for more details.

Comment: Great Thanks for your reply and helping me, Is it right or should i use RealDoubleFFT class to FFT transform ?

Comment: this is the link for RealDoubleFFT class
[link](http://herschel.esac.esa.int/hcss-doc-10.0/load/hcss_drm/api/herschel/ia/numeric/toolbox/xform/util/RealDoubleFFT.html)

Comment: please give me an answer .. this is the last hint in this project i think :)

Comment: It doesn't really matter what FFT you use, so long as it works and the performance is acceptable.

Comment: Is there any way to test results ?

Comment: Sure - create a sine wave at a known frequency, pass it through your FFT and peak finding code, then check that you get the expected frequency. Note also that you should apply a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_.28Hanning.29_window) prior to your FFT.

Comment: sorry, can you give me an example about how to apply this sine in java ?

Comment: Just create a buffer of the same type and size that you use for input currently, then fill it with samples of a sine wave (e.g. `buff[i] = a * sin(2 * pi * f * i / fs);` where `a` is the amplitude, `f` is the frequency, `fs` is the sample rate)