# How can I get DFT/FFT output frequencies in Hertz?

Tags: c, audio, fft, dft

I want to develop musical notes detector as my degree project and I want to do it from scratch. I have written code for ".wav" file which extracts all info from that audio music file and gives me amplitude as a result.

Then I have written a code for DFT - it gives me output as a complex number where one of the axis (real/imaginary) is amplitude/magnitude and other is Phase.

Now the question I want the answer in frequency (in Hertz not in vector) so I can check whether my DFT gives me the proper output or not. How can i convert my DFT output into frequency ?

I have to code this in C language and I don't want to use any built-in library

Comment: When you say the real axis is amplitude and the imaginary is phase, are you calculating that yourself? Or just pulling that straight from the DFT? When you get the complex result from a DFT, the amplitude is the absolute value of that result, and the phase is the angle (aka argument) of the result.

Comment: Yes I am calculating DFT myself,means I got the formula which is " Sigma From k=0 -> N-1 ,For all f(x)* W*N,here W*N=e^(-i 2 PI /N)" like this ...I  just convert this formula into my C program.

Comment: The bin frequency at the peak FFT magnitude is very often not the note pitch in music audio.

Comment: @hotpaw2, I learned this the hard way. What is the correct approach to finding the dominant pitch in a audio clip, then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to find the peak *magnitude* then work out the corresponding frequency:

- calculate the magnitude of each DFT output bin: `magnitude = sqrt(re*re+im*im)`
- find the bin with the largest magnitude, call its index `i_max`.
- calculate the equivalent frequency of this bin: `freq = i_max * Fs / N`, here `Fs` = sample rate (Hz) and `N` = no of points in FFT.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627) for a more detailed explanation of how bin indices and frequency are related.

Comment: Sorry Paul R  but i did not get it.I also had calculated the magnitude from my DFT result.Now the question is i have to find i_max for each window (1024 samples)? And as per what i read about DFT i just find that magnitude on the 512 sample which is N/2 where i get maximum. m i right.means i want to asj dat ..And also thank you very much..:)