# Calculating Hertz of STFT

Tags: audio, fft, dft

This question is mainly related to this answer: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390677/how-can-i-get-dft-fft-output-frequencies-in-hertz?answertab=votes#tab-top) so would be ideal if @Paul R has a chance to look at it.

I have a signal, which I have computed a STFT on. The size of the NFFT is 256 with an overlap of 128. This has produced 21 separate blocks containing the output.

I would like to therefore convert this into Hertz to see what the different Hertz are for each of these points within the signals. I have computed the magnitude using the following formula:

```
sqrt(output[i][j].re * output[i][j].re + output[i][j].im * output[i][j].im)
```

This produces the following:

[image]

I'm mainly confused with how the next part works. For example I essentially have a 2D vector containing all of the blocks from the STFT (each of size 256). Do I therefore calculate the magnitude for each of the points within the block, calculate the highest number of the magnitude and then use the formula `freq = i_max * Fs / N`?

If so, would it look something like the following (An example, not actual data):

```
D0 = {0.23 + 1.58, 
      1.05 + 0.56, 
      0.58 + 1.38, 
      ....., 
      0.58 + 87.6} 
      = mag[0] = sqrt(0.23 * 0.23 + 1.58 * 1.58),
        ....
        ....
```

This would then produce vector of magnitudes for each of the STFT output. From there, I can calculate which is the highest (Let's say 7) and then I can compute the following:

```
freq = 7 * 44100 / 4
```

Where 44100 = Sample rate and 4 = size of the STFT block.

This would then give me what frequency each of the blocks are.

Is this correct, or, am I missing the point completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing a few things, your output image seems to be the all 21 blocks (FFT) together 21 * 256 = 5376 points, it's really not help nothing !

You need find the fundamental frequency for every block (NFFT=256) using:

```
freq = MaxMagnitudeFromThisBlockFFT * Fs / NFFT
```

For your case:

```
freq = MaxMagnitudeFromThisBlockFFT * 44100 / 256
```

At the end you will find 21 frequencies one for each block FFT

PS:

Your NFFT is 256 and your sample rate is 44100, then your frequency resolution is 44100/ 256 = 172,265625, if you want more accurate try NFFT= 2048 or 4096.

Comment: Hi, the thing is. For the STFT, I will be using a spectrogram, which seems to already finds the magnitude. `10 * log10(sqrt(re*re + im * im)` So do I just need to calculate the highest number for these bins and then calculate the htz? For example, can the result from the spectrogram be used here/

Comment: I never use spectrogram to calculate it, I aways use the magnetude equation **sqrt(re*re+im*im)** and this is the right way, now all that you need is get the maximun value (index) from first half results ...

Comment: Thanks this works!! Just don't calculate using the spectrogram? Got it :)! Will I most likely see a change in htz from the blocks? I.e. if a block is lower than the other, I assume the freq will increase vice versa ?

Comment: cool that worked, each block have no relation if your frequency will increase or decrease, just depends of your input signal

Comment: So this method would not be suitable for showing how the frequency changes over time then?

Comment: You can build an Frequency Histogram, that show to you in one graphic how the frequency from your signal change over the time !

or are you looking for a spectrum analyzer? like it (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw6jbAbvsvo)???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44971/discussion-between-ederwander-and-user1326876)