# Why are my frequency values for iPhone FFT incorrect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I've been trying to get exact frequencies using the FFT in Apple's Accelerate framework, but I'm having trouble working out why my values are off the true frequency.

I have been using this article http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/ as the basis for my implementation, and after really struggling to get to the point I'm at now, I am totally stumped.

So far I've got audio in -> Hanning window -> FFT -> phase calculation -> weird final output. I'd think that there will be a problem with my maths somewhere, but I'm really out of ideas by now.

The outputs are a lot lower what they should be, e.g., I input 440Hz and it prints out 190Hz, or I input 880Hz and it prints out 400Hz. For the most part these results are consistent, but not always, and there doesn't seem to be any common factor between anything either...

Here is my code:

```
enum
{
    sampleRate  = 44100,
    osamp       = 4,
    samples     = 4096,
    range       = samples * 7 / 16,
    step        = samples / osamp
};

NSMutableArray *fftResults;

static COMPLEX_SPLIT    A;
static FFTSetup         setupReal;
static uint32_t         log2n, n, nOver2;
static int32_t          stride;

static float            expct = 2*M_PI*((double)step/(double)samples);
static float            phase1[range];
static float            phase2[range];
static float            dPhase[range];

- (void)fftSetup
{
    // Declaring integers
    log2n = 12;
    n = 1 << log2n;
    stride = 1;
    nOver2 = n / 2;

    // Allocating memory for complex vectors
    A.realp = (float *) malloc(nOver2 * sizeof(float));
    A.imagp = (float *) malloc(nOver2 * sizeof(float));

    // Allocating memory for FFT
    setupReal = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, FFT_RADIX2);

    // Setting phase
    memset(phase2, 0, range * sizeof(float));

}
        // For each sample in buffer...
        for (int bufferCount = 0; bufferCount < audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; bufferCount++)
        {
            // Declaring samples from audio buffer list
            SInt16 *samples = (SInt16*)audioBufferList.mBuffers[bufferCount].mData;


            // Creating Hann window function
            for (int i = 0; i < nOver2; i++)
            {
                double hannMultiplier = 0.5 * (1 - cos((2 * M_PI * i) / (nOver2 -  1)));

                // Applying window to each sample
                A.realp[i] = hannMultiplier * samples[i];
                A.imagp[i] = 0;
            }

            // Applying FFT
            vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &A, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

            // Detecting phase
            vDSP_zvphas(&A, stride, phase1, stride, range);

            // Calculating phase difference
            vDSP_vsub(phase2, stride, phase1, stride, dPhase, stride, range);

            // Saving phase
            memcpy(phase2, phase1, range * sizeof(float));

            // Extracting DSP outputs
            for (size_t j = 0; j < nOver2; j++)
            {
                NSNumber *realNumbers = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:A.realp[j]];
                NSNumber *imagNumbers = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:A.imagp[j]];

                [real addObject:realNumbers];
                [imag addObject:imagNumbers];

            }

            // Combining real and imaginary parts
            [resultsCombined addObject:real];
            [resultsCombined addObject:imag];

            // Filling FFT output array
            [fftResults addObject:resultsCombined];
        }

    }


    int fftCount = [fftResults count];
    NSLog(@"FFT Count: %d",fftCount);

    // For each FFT...
    for (int i = 0; i < fftCount; i++)
    {
        // Declaring integers for peak detection
        float peak = 0;
        float binNumber = 0;

        // Declaring integers for phase detection
        float deltaPhase;

        static float trueFrequency[range];


        for (size_t j = 1; j < range; j++)
        {
            // Calculating bin magnitiude
            float realVal   = [[[[fftResults objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
            float imagVal   = [[[[fftResults objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
            float magnitude = sqrtf(realVal*realVal + imagVal*imagVal);

            // Peak detection
            if (magnitude > peak)
            {
                peak = magnitude;
                binNumber = (float)j;
            }

            // Getting phase difference
            deltaPhase = dPhase[j];

            // Subtract expected difference
            deltaPhase -= (float)j*expct;

            // Map phase difference into +/- pi interval
            int qpd = deltaPhase / M_PI;

            if (qpd >= 0)
                qpd += qpd&1;
            else
                qpd -= qpd&1;

            deltaPhase -= M_PI * (float)qpd;

            // Getting bin deviation from +/i interval
            float deltaFrequency = osamp * deltaPhase / (2 * M_PI);

            // Calculating true frequency at the j-th partial
            trueFrequency[j] = (j * (sampleRate/samples)) + (deltaFrequency * (sampleRate/samples));

        }

        UInt32 mag;
        mag = binNumber;

        // Extracting frequency at bin peak
        float f = trueFrequency[mag];

        NSLog(@"True frequency = %fHz", f);

        float b = roundf(binNumber*(sampleRate/nOver2));

        NSLog(@" Bin frequency = %fHz", b);

    }
```

Comment: Have a look here, I don't think you are actually converting FFT output index to actual frequency!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result

Comment: I've looked through that and I have already got the bin output (last 2 lines of code) that is being talked about there, is that what you are referring to? I am after the exact frequencies, and I think my problem lies in my phase calculations, that page doesn't seem to touch on that... Unless I am misinterpreting what you are saying!

Comment: can you explain why the phase influences the exact frequencies? shouldn't it not only influence the power?

Comment: It was my understanding that if a frequency is equal to a bin frequency then it will have no phase difference, however if the frequency is different to a bin freq. then its phase can be used to calculate how far off the bin frequency it is: i.e. exact frequency = delta frequency + bin frequency, where delta frequency is calculated via this phase. Well I think this at least, as my program doesn't work!

Comment: fft has only limited frequency resolution equaling the bin width. the phase is not doing what you expect. If you follow the link trumpetlicks has posted you should be fine.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I don't follow how that link is of any help. My code is able to match my input to the nearest FFT bin, which as far as I can see is what that question is talking about. I am after the exact frequencies, which I know is possible through implementing phase  (this is a very in depth article on the matter: http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/). Am I missing something you are talking about perhaps? Getting FFT results from the frequency bins is not precise enough for my requirements...

Comment: I didn't know the usage of STFTs and phase analysis for improved resolution respectively better estimations.

Comment: Phase vocoder uses 2 or more offset FFTs to produce a frequency estimate with higher resolution than a single FFT bin width.  The phase difference is used for this phase vocoder estimate. It's a common technique used with overlapped window STFT processing.

Comment: Test by making sure each FFT peak magnitude bin frequency estimate (with no phase correction factor) is correct (to bin resolution).  Phase correcting the wrong bin in the wrong direction will produce bad results.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I've got a phase difference when my frequency matches the bins. I guess my focus will be on why thats happening, though I am still pretty clueless at the moment... Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Note that the expected phase difference (even for a bin-centered frequency) depends on both the window offset or overlap of the FFT pairs, and the bin number or frequency of the FFT result.  e.g. If you offset the windows by very little (1 sample), then the unwrapped phase difference between 2 FFTs will be smaller than with a larger offset.  At the same offset, if the frequency is higher, the expected phase difference between the same bin of two FFTs will be greater (or it will wrap more).