# How to treat a vector returned by Eigen's FFT?

Tags: c++, vector, fft, frequency, eigen

Assuming that I convert a vector in time domain to frequency domain in C++ using Eigen's FFT. What FFT gives in return is a vector of complex numbers. My question is that how can I filter this (output) vector for some specific frequency and get the amplitude of that frequency.

```
vector<float> Tdomain(N);
vector<std::complex<float> > Fdomain;
Eigen::FFT<float> fft;
fft.fwd(Fdomain,Tdomain);
```

Or how can I even know if the given vector (the frequency domain) contains a specific frequency?
This procedure seems to be more straightforward and visual in MATLAB, but how I can do it in C++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be much the same as for any other FFT implementation, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627 for the frequency relationship.

Comment: Agree. Pretty much the only difference with MATLAB is that DC is at 0, not 1, and TBH having DC at index 0 is the sane thing anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I was however searching for duplicate questions for a while. Maybe the Eigen keyword limited my results.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR for the link. If you found more information please don't hesitate to share them.