# FFT window output about 10% off Python

Tags: python, fft

I am writing code that takes windows of 1024 samples each of a sine wave, takes the FFT of each window, and returns the maximum frequency of each window. I know they will all be the same for a sine wave, but it's for testing. My code works mostly, except the resulting frequencies seem to be about 10 percent lower than they should be. For example, a sine of 440Hz results in a max amplitude at frequency 430 in my FFT. I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this. Any suggestions?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as py
from scipy import fftpack
from pylab import *
import scipy.io.wavfile

def PARTA(window):

    sr = 44100
    x = arange(0., 2*pi, 1./sr)
    samples = sin(2*pi*440*x)

    time_step = 1. / sr

    end = len(samples)/window
    print end
    '''Make a 2-D array of samples'''
    windowed = []
    maxes = []
    for i in range(0, end):
        windowed.append(samples[i*window:(i+1)*window])
    for j in range(0, end):
        ps = np.abs(np.fft.fft(windowed[j]))**2
        freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(windowed[j].size, time_step)
        max_y = max(ps)  # Find the maximum y value
        max_x = freqs[ps.argmax()]  # Find the x value corresponding to the    maximum y value
        maxes.append(max_x)
    end2 = float(len(samples)/sr)
    #print end2
    interval = end2/end
    #print interval
    x = arange(0., end2, interval)
    y = []
    for i in range(0, len(maxes)):
        y.append(abs(maxes[i]))
    return (x, y)

x, y = PARTA(1024)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just that your FFT has very coarse resolution, since it only has 1024 bins. Each bin in your FFT has a resolution of `44100 / 1024 = 43.1 Hz`. Your 440 Hz peak will be at bin index 10 which has a corresponding centre frequency of `10 * 44100 / 1024 = 430.66 Hz`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056) for more detail on FFT bin indices and corresponding frequencies.