# What is the Output of a fftLeft array after applying FFTDb function to a waveLeft array C# .Frequencies, or something else?

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft, audio-streaming, frequency-analysis

I am a newcomer to the sound programming. I have a real-time sound visualizer(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20025/Sound-visualizer-in-C). I downloaded it from codeproject.com.

In AudioFrame.cs class there is an array as below:

```
_fftLeft = FourierTransform.FFTDb(ref _waveLeft);
```

`_fftLeft` is a double array. `_waveLeft` is also a double array. As above they applied 
FouriorTransform.cs class's FFTDb function to a _waveLeft array.

Here is FFTDb function:

```
static public double[] FFTDb(ref double[] x)
    {

        n = x.Length;
        nu = (int)(Math.Log(n) / Math.Log(2));
        int n2 = n / 2;
        int nu1 = nu - 1;
        double[] xre = new double[n];
        double[] xim = new double[n];
        double[] decibel = new double[n2];
        double tr, ti, p, arg, c, s;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            xre[i] = x[i];
            xim[i] = 0.0f;
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (int l = 1; l <= nu; l++)
        {
            while (k < n)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++)
                {
                    p = BitReverse(k >> nu1);
                    arg = 2 * (double)Math.PI * p / n;
                    c = (double)Math.Cos(arg);
                    s = (double)Math.Sin(arg);
                    tr = xre[k + n2] * c + xim[k + n2] * s;
                    ti = xim[k + n2] * c - xre[k + n2] * s;
                    xre[k + n2] = xre[k] - tr;
                    xim[k + n2] = xim[k] - ti;
                    xre[k] += tr;
                    xim[k] += ti;
                    k++;
                }
                k += n2;
            }
            k = 0;
            nu1--;
            n2 = n2 / 2;
        }
        k = 0;
        int r;
        while (k < n)
        {
            r = BitReverse(k);
            if (r > k)
            {
                tr = xre[k];
                ti = xim[k];
                xre[k] = xre[r];
                xim[k] = xim[r];
                xre[r] = tr;
                xim[r] = ti;
            }
            k++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            decibel[i] = 10.0 * Math.Log10((float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i]))));
        return decibel;
    }
```

When I play a music note in a guitar i wanted to know it's frequency in a numerical format. I wrote a foreach loop to know what is the output of a _fftLeft array as below,

```
  foreach (double myarray in _fftLeft)

            {
                Console.WriteLine(myarray );
            }
```

This output's contain lots of  real-time values as below .

```
41.3672743963389
,43.0176034462662,
35.3677383746087,
42.5968946936404,
42.0600935794783,
36.7521669642071,
41.6356709559342,
41.7189032845742,
41.1002451261724,
40.8035583510188,
45.604366914128,
39.645552593115
```

I want to know what are those values (frequencies or not)? if the answer is frequencies then why it contains low frequency values? And when I play a guitar note I want to detect a frequency of that particular guitar note.

Comment: Based on the punctuation and capitalization errors, it looks like you're posting from a cell phone.  In the future, I suggest you use a real computer; we require a bit more precision than this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the posted code, `FFTDb` first computes the [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) then computes and returns the magnitudes of the frequency spectrum in the logarithmic decibels scale. In other words, the `_fftLeft` then contains *magnitudes* for a discreet set of frequencies. The actual values of those frequencies can be computed using the array index and sampling frequency according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/2994596).

As an example, if you were plotting the `_fftLeft` output for a pure sinusoidal tone input you should be able to see a clear spike in the index corresponding to the sinusoidal frequency. For a guitar note however you are likely going to see multiple spikes in magnitude corresponding to the harmonics. To detect the note's frequency aka pitch is a more complicated topic and typically requires the use of one of several [pitch detection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm).