# Designing 2D DFT filter that works with cycle per degree?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, dft, vision

Here is my question regarding 2d dft.
I know how to do 2d-dft and convolution and filtering. However,  I still have a basic question.
Maybe I have not understand the concept, and that's why I don't know what to do here.

So basically, When we want to filter the spatial frequency content of scenes  via by multiplying the Fourier transformation of original images by Gaussian
filters. How can I  removed spatial frequency content above 0.5, 1, and 2 cycles per degree (cpd; low-pass cut-offs of 12, 24, 49 cycles per image).

Also we know that on of the Gaussian filter is a function of the spatial frequency cut-off, for a standard attenuation of 3 dB.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: may be you would have better luck in http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ with this.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in this matter but I would approach your task like this:

First just to be sure I hope you know that FFT returns **Nyquist frequencies** only. So if you remove band of **Nyquist frequencies** from FFT that does not mean that reconstructed image will have no frequencies in removed band (due to aliasing)!!! Also I recommend to read:

- [How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in a FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/2521214).

Now as you want the spacial units instead `Hz` then let:

- `xs,ys` be the image size
- `FFT[xs][ys]` be the FFT result

So analogically in `x` axis:

- `FFT[1][?]` represents `1 cpi` (cycle per image)
- `FFT[2][?]` represents `2 cpi` (cycle per image)
- `FFT[xs-1][?]` represents `(xs-1) cpi` (cycle per image)

Hope everyone can guess the `y` axis from this on your own. Now we now which part of **FFT** result belong to which spatial frequencies. So:

1. **construct matrix `M[xs][ys]` holding filter coefficients**

   - set `M[x][y]=1.0` for all frequencies that are passing your filter
   - set the rest to `M[x][y]=0.0`
   - do not forget to always set `M[0][0]=1.0` otherwise you broke the `DC` part of the result
2. **to simulate not sharp filtering**

   You can Gaussian blur matrix `M` the radius'es of Gaussian blur ellipse can be dependent on the `x,y` position.
3. **Multiply `FFT[][]` and `M[][]` element-wise**

   `FFT[x][y]=FFT[x][y]*M[x][y]`
4. **now reconstruct the image**

   `image=IFFT(FFT[][])`