# How do i get the frequency of a sine wave out of FFT fourier?

Tags: c#, fft, frequency

So i have a array of floats where FFT has already been performed on.
Now i have a array full of values, but how do i get the main frequency out of that?
I have tried this that i found on another page([How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-do-i-obtain-the-frequencies-of-each-value-in-a-fft)) but it doesn't work with my code.

Where FloatArray is where all the values of the FFT process are stored, and freq is a list where the freq of each value is stored

```
         List<float> freq=new List<float>();

        for(int i=0;i<FloatArray.Length/2;i++)
        {
            float ja = (i * values.sampleRate) / FloatArray.Length;
            freq.Add(ja);
        }
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work with my code"* - what is exactly not working?

Comment: The output of your FFT should be *complex value pairs* - how are these stored ? Or did you already calculate the complex *magnitude* ?

Comment: I get values from 0 to 16383 followed by -16383 to -10718. How do i get my main frequency out of this?

Comment: You're looking for a peak *magnitude* in the FFT output - calculate the *magnitude* for each bin, find the largest bin magnitude, then take the *index* of this peak magnitude and convert it to a frequency.

Comment: I found the peak magnitude but its always the first one in the array is this correct?

Comment: The first value is the DC offset.  If the DC offset is larger than any sinusoid present, then that is correct.