# Can frequency bin index be decimal number?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I am calculating frequency bin index `k` with formula

```
k = f_k * N / Fs + 1,
```

where sample rate is `Fs`, the number of samples in the FFT is `N`, then the frequency of the bin with Matlab index `k` is `f_k`. But  I get that `k` is decimal number, and it needs to be integer because I use it later like index for Fourier transformed series. I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each bin represents a *range* of frequencies (the width of each bin is `Fs / N`). The bin which corresponds to your frequency of interest is `round(f_k * N / Fs)` (`+ 1` if you're using MATLAB's 1-based indexing), i.e. this is where most of your signal energy will appear, although there will be some energy in adjacent bins too, due to [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) (you should of course use a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to minimise this).

Further reading: [How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is convert k to an integer using round. 
You will have to recalculate your other variables for them to adjust to the integer value of k. I do not see how this could bother you too much.

Digital signal processing is based on a lot of approximation anyways.

Hope that helps out

Comment: I agree, I just modified my post. Thanks for the input