# FFT result interpretation

Tags: java, fft, frequency-domain

I am developing an android app that will do human activity recognition. I am using Apache Commons to calculate my time domain features already. Now, I want to use Fast Fourier Transform method of the library to convert my time domain data (raw xyz values) from the accelerometer to the frequency domain. I am not sure how to interpret the result. Am I correct to interpret the result as a bin corresponding to each of the frequency for the values of X (for example) at each of those frequencies?

This is the code I have:

```
public class MyFFT {

public static void computeFFT(double[] input) {
    FastFourierTransformer transformer = new FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.STANDARD);
    Complex[] complexResults = transformer.transform(input, TransformType.FORWARD);

    for(Complex c:complexResults){
        System.out.println(c.getReal());
    }
    System.out.println(complexResults.toString());
}
}
```

And its usage:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] xValues = new double[]{0.5,1.5,1.2,0.5,0.8,1.5,1.9,2.9};

    MyFFT.computeFFT(xValues);
}
}
```

Output:

```
10.8
1.3970562748477138
-1.7999999999999998
-1.9970562748477145
-2.0
-1.9970562748477139
-1.7999999999999998
 1.3970562748477144
```

Comment: See [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056) which explains how FFT bin outputs relate to frequency.

Comment: FFT bins are exactly the same as DFT bins. The 'F' is just an implementation detail. The real part of a DFT bin is not very interesting. You probably want to look at magnitude instead.

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm hey, thank you for your reply. I will definitely check the output out the magnitude.

Comment: For one thing, ignoring the imaginary component of the FFT results makes no sense at all. You probably want a power spectrum. I highly recommend you do some reading on the mathematics of FFT , power spectra, zero-padding data series, etc.  There are assumptions involved in FFTs that can't be ignored when you interpret them. A little bit of knowledge about FFTs is a dangerous thing.