# How to extract frequency from 32-bit float array using FFT in c++

Tags: c++, mp3, fft, shazam

I'm writing a small sound recognition program in C++. So I have an mp3 file which I sampled using mpg123 and got a 32-bit float array. Now I passed this array to FFT function and got some data. How do I extract frequencies?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @chingachgook, I hope that you will take the time to review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because this question lacks the detail required for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Some data" returned by FFT, must be a signal frequency spectrum. Probably it is an array of complex numbers, and to find "most powerful" frequency, you need to find an element with maximum absolute value (modulus). To calculate frequency, ... *here was my mistake* ... follow a link in Paul R's comment.

Comment: The last sentence regarding calculating frequency is not quite right: see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056).

Comment: Oh, indeed, my bad.