# FFT results interpretation

Tags: fft, fftw, ifft, cufft

I used excel to transform my time domain data to the frequency domain, the results I got were complex numbers, of which I obtained the absolute value using imabs in excel. Now I am confused, are these absolute values the amplitudes in certain frequencies? if so then what frequency do they correspond to?.
Given that my sampling rate was 1sample per each 0.0000004 sec. and the total number N of points which I transformed using FFT were 2048.

Comment: Please share your code. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056) for an explanation of how FFT indices map to frequency.

Comment: The link Paul suggests will answer your question