# How to obtain wavenumber of FFT?

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a series of 192 data in a 3.14(m) domain.
I use the "fft" command to plot the energy spectrum.
How can I calculate wavenumber(k) of each grid?

Code:

```
data= load('data.txt');
PHI = fft(data);
% K=?? ;
%loglog(K,abs(PHI));
```

Comment: I think you have to provide some more details to your question as it is unclear what you actually want to achieve. Also, please have a look at how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The wavenumbers are uniformly spaced spatial frequencies, obtained in a similar fashion as the [FFT bin frequencies for temporal signals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627). You can thus compute them using the following:

```
K = [0:(len(data)-1)]/len(data) * (192/3.14);
```

Note that this give meaningful wavenumbers up to the Nyquist limit of `len(data)/2 - 1`. Above that you may prefer to use negative wavenumbers :

```
N = len(data);
K = [[0:(floor(N/2)-1)] ; [floor(N/2):(N-1)]-N]/N * (192/3.14);
```