# How do I know the target Hz in data fourier-transformed by librosa

Tags: python, scipy, librosa

I am using `librosa` to get `stft`.

```
frame = 2048
a = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=frame,hop_length= int(frame /4), window='hann')
```

`librosa.stft` returns `np.ndarray [shape=(1 + n_fft/2, t), dtype=dtype]`

so `a`'s dimension is (1025,***)

OK, 1025 is frequency classification.

However, how do I know which index in array correspond to each Hz??

For example when I want to mute under 440Hz, which is correct??

```
a[:10] = 0 
a[:100] = 0
a[:150] = 0
```

How do I know the correct array index?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the frequencies associated with STFT in Librosa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350459/getting-the-frequencies-associated-with-stft-in-librosa)

Comment: Thank you verymuch, that's exactly what I want to know.