# How to obtain frequencies in Non-Uniform DFFT?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have code that looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from nfft import nfft


# number of sample points
N = 400

# Simulated non-uniform data
x = np.linspace(0.0, 1 / 2, N) + np.random.random((N)) * 0.001
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x) + 0.5 * np.sin(80.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x)
yf = np.abs(nfft(x, y))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)
fig_f, axs_f = plt.subplots(1)

axs.plot(x, y, '.', color='red')
axs_f.plot(x, yf, color='red')
```

[image: graphs produced by code]

How do I convert the values on the second graph to represent frequency?

The use of the `nfft` module is not required, answers using `pynfft` or `scipy` will be greatly appreciated.

See also:
[How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-do-i-obtain-the-frequencies-of-each-value-in-an-fft/4371627#4371627)

Comment: I think we have an answer for your question, check it out, see if it works for you, and let me know.

Comment: Tested and it works, thanks!

Comment: It case it might be of help, generally when I need a nonuniform transform, I just do the explicit FT, c.f.  sum  A_t e_{ i f t}, over all of the (A_t,t) in the data set , and iterate over the f of interest.   Modern computers are often fast enough, and data sets are often small enough, that the "fast" in FFT is not so important.

Comment: Back then, I looked at the FFT (and to some extent still do) as a magic box that gets frequencies; A comment like that would have been a godsend. Thanks once again!

Comment: Another important comment would be to mention windowing.  Any finite set of points has an implicit window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work.  Notice the line inserted before graphing the Fourier transform, to generate the frequencies, and that we graph N/2 of the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from nfft import nfft

# number of sample points
N = 400

# Simulated non-uniform data
x = np.linspace(0.0,0.5-0.02, N) + np.random.random((N)) * 0.001
print(x)

print( 'random' )
print( np.random.random((N)) * 0.001 )

y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x) + 0.5 * np.sin(80.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x)
yf = np.abs(nfft(x, y))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)
fig_f, axs_f = plt.subplots(1)

axs.plot(x, y, '.', color='red')

xf = np.fft.fftfreq(N,1./N)

axs_f.plot(xf[:int(N/2)], yf[:int(N/2)], color='red')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: excuse me, what nfft library is this?

Comment: @mastro   There are a few non uniform FFT (NFFT) libraries on PyPI.  The one simply called "nfft" was around when the question was posted.  Maybe that one is it.