# If there any way to get frequency of sound.

Tags: iphone, signal-processing, fft, dft

I want to know the frequency of data. I had a little bit idea that it can be done using FFT, but I am not sure how to do it. Once I passed the entire data to FFT, then it is giving me 2 peaks, but how can I get the frequency?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The position of the peaks are the frequency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Frequency from FFT result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)

Comment: This is asked so often on SE I wrote a blog post explaining it with code: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this page for an explanation on how to calculate it:
[FFT Fundamentals](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372416B-01/svtconcepts/fft_funda/)

Please also check this answer (it's C# code but I think you can easily understand it)
[How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result/4371627#4371627)

And finally have a look at this one, it uses DFT instead of FFT:
[Determining the magnitude of a certain frequency on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921674/determining-the-magnitude-of-a-certain-frequency-on-the-iphone/2937762#2937762)

I also found this implementation that you can use in Objective-C:

A lib to find the frequency https://github.com/jkells/sc_listener
A example using the above library https://github.com/jkells/sc_listener_sample

Regards

Answer (score 1):

An FFT will give you the frequency of all the sinusoidal components of a signal.  If instead you want just the frequency of the periodicity of common waveforms (more interesting sounding and looking that a plain sinewave) such as produced by speech and music, then you may want to use a pitch detection/estimation algorithm instead of just an FFT peak.